# Taylor expansion on a Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, taylor-expansion, riemannian-geometry

Is there a way to define the Taylor expansion of a function $f:\mathcal{M}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where $\mathcal{M}$ is a smooth manifold? I'm looking for a free coordinate definition. I guess it is necessary to equip $\mathcal{M}$ with a linear connection (covariant derivative).

Comment: The Taylor expansion of a function is usually not only defined but written down in terms of coordinates, so it would help if you could clarify exactly what kind of object you were looking for. One related notion is that of *jet bundles*: Two functions $f, g$ define the same $k$-jet at $p \in M$ if $f - g$ vanishes to order $k$ at $p$. (This is "coordinate-free" if you're happy to accept "vanishes to order $k$ at $p$ as a coordinate-free statement). In this way, the Taylor expansion of the function $g$ at $p$ is something like the $\infty$-jet $j^{\infty}(f)(p)$.

Comment: (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_bundle#Algebraic-geometric_perspective for more about jets and the infinite jet sheaf $\mathcal{J}^\infty(TM)$.)

Comment: You can define coordinate-free Taylor expansions up to a certain order using jets, but you cannot identity the individual orders since they are not tensorial. Using a connection you can separate the contribution from the function (Hessian) and the curvature or non-geodesic nature along which you expand. Also note that at a critical point the Hessian is always well defined without a connection.

Comment: By the way, not all smooth functions have a taylor expansion which converges to the function. This is same as saying that there are smooth functions which are not analytic.